# Uncaught TypeError on Angular 4 app hosted on IIS

Tags: angular, typescript, iis, webpack

I have hosted an Angular 4 app using IIS.  The Angular 4 app works fine when accessed by two machines that were actively developing the Angular 4 app, but any other computer that accesses the Angular 4 app returns an `" 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function' common.es5.js:3084".`

I haven't seen this before and I do not know what this is referring to.  Does something need to be installed on the server?  I assume the two development machines have something installed on them that allows them to access the Angular 4 app that other machines do not.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very unlikely that this is because something was "downloaded on these machines". Rather, the browsers of the non-developer machines seem to be missing support for certain Javascript functions ([aka they are older browsers](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7221)).

To remedy this, you will likely need to add a polyfill to your angular build, which would add in newer Javascript functionality for older browsers.  However, without specifically looking at your code, it is hard to tell what in particular you would need to add.

Comment: I apologise Derek, you were 100% right.  I incorrectly checked the wrong version of the 'standard' Chrome image.  The development machines had another version of Chrome (separate to the corporate image) which I didn't realise they were using.  I've never used Polyfills, so I'll have to figure that out.  Thanks again!

Comment: To add onto this answer, I simply opened the polyfills.ts file within the app folder created by the Angular CLI and uncommented all the 'import es6' scripts. I re-ran 'ng build --prod' and everything works perfectly. Thanks again Derek!